# PARTITION BY syntax error - how to get partitioned result set

Tags: mysql, sql, database, partition, sql-function

My query:

```
SELECT education,nickname,height
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY education ORDER BY height DESC) INDEX_NUM
FROM user
LIMIT 100;
```

My table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE user (

female BOOLEAN NOT NULL,

nickname VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
id INT NOT NULL,
charm INT NOT NULL,
standardmember BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
idcard BOOLEAN NOT NULL,

age INT NOT NULL,
marriage VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
region VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,

education VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
height INT NOT NULL,
weight INT NOT NULL,
constellation VARCHAR(5),
race VARCHAR(5),
animalzodiac VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,

intro TEXT NOT NULL,

rage VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
rheight VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
rrace VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
reducation VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
rphoto VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
rmarriage VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
rregion VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
rhonesty VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,

jobtitle VARCHAR(15),
industry VARCHAR(20),
companynature VARCHAR(10),
employeewelfare VARCHAR(10),
workintensity VARCHAR(10),
mobility VARCHAR(10),
careervsfamily VARCHAR(10),
overseaassignment VARCHAR(10),

college VARCHAR(30),
majortype VARCHAR(5),
languages VARCHAR(50),

birthplace VARCHAR(10),
residence VARCHAR(10),
nationality VARCHAR(15),
personality VARCHAR(5),
humor VARCHAR(6),
temper VARCHAR(6),
seriousness VARCHAR(15),
kidwish VARCHAR(5),
whentomarry VARCHAR(5),
longdistancelove VARCHAR(5),
dreammarriage TEXT,

livewithparents VARCHAR(5),
parents VARCHAR(5),
siblings VARCHAR(25),
financialsituation VARCHAR(10),
parentsinsurance VARCHAR(10),
parentsemployment VARCHAR(35),

sent BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;

PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

);

My goal is to divide the result set and sort them into a height-ascending order. Like this:

[image: my goal]

But I got the error:

[image: syntax error]

Well, I'm not so good with MySQL and query syntaxes. Feel to free to teach me if I asked a stupid question. Thx.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql

Comment: You should post sample data and errors as text, not images. Text is searchable; images are not (and worse when you just link them off-site). Anyway, I'm interested to know what you thought that syntax would work!

Comment: Sorry, it's my first time asking a question here in StackOverflow. I will follow your advice next time. Thank you! @underscore_d

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT education,
       nickname,
       height,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER w AS INDEX_NUM
FROM u
WINDOW w AS (
             PARTITION BY education,
             nickname ORDER BY height DESC 
             );
```

Here I used the `ROW_NUMBER` with Window functions.
Since MySQL supports nonaggregate functions that are used only as window functions. For these, the OVER clause is mandatory like:

```
CUME_DIST()
DENSE_RANK()
FIRST_VALUE()
LAG()
LAST_VALUE()
LEAD()
NTH_VALUE()
NTILE()
PERCENT_RANK()
RANK()
ROW_NUMBER()
```

For more info follow the below link:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html

Comment: What was the problem, and how did you solve it? A good answer would include this info.

Comment: Step 1:  Upgrade to 8.0.